# Number of terms containing primitive root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

It is well known that the degree of the n-th cyclotomic polynomial is $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. I define the ${minimal}$ sum to be of the form

\begin{align}
\xi_0 + \sum_{i=1 }^{k} \xi_i = 0
\end{align}

where $\xi_0$ an non-negative integer, $\xi_i$'s roots of unity of some order, and no subsum on the left sums to 0. If the sum were to have $\xi_n$, the primitive n-th root, as one of the terms, does the fact that the n-th cyclotomic polynomial have degree $\varphi(n)$ imply that this minimal sum has $\varphi(n)$ terms?

Comment: It has degree $\varphi(n)$, but that means that the polynomial may consist of up to $\varphi(n)+1$ terms.

Comment: I don't think minimal polynomial was the right term to use. I rephrased my question a bit.

Comment: If $\xi$ is of order $8$, then $\xi^4+\xi^0=0$, and we only have two terms. Is that what you mean? The same can be achieved as $\xi^5+\xi^1=0$, and now both terms are primitive of order eight.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah yes. I forgot 1 restriction: the sum also needs to have a constant term. I'll rephrase my question again, sorry.

Comment: But $\sum_{i=1}^k\xi$ is just $k\xi$. Do you mean $\sum_{\xi\in A}\xi$ where $A$ is a set of primitive roots? If so, why tack on the constant term? It's a bit bizarre and arbitrary to speak of "a sum of primitive roots, oh and a rational number."

Comment: Yeah, your notation is unclear. You should probably use a subscript: $\xi_i$? Did you meant that: 1) the terms should all be roots of unity of the same order, 2) they should all be distinct, 3) one of them should be primitive, and 4) one of them should be rational, i.e. $=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not functioning correctly at this hour. $\xi$ is a n-th root of unity of some order, and $\xi_0$ is an integer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, spot on. I'll make more edits.

Comment: But if $\xi$ is just *one* root of unity - i.e. every summand in the sum is equal - then the sum is just $\xi+\cdots+\xi=k\xi$ and this problem becomes trivial.

Comment: And if $\xi$ is of order $25$, then $1+\xi^5+\xi^{10}+\xi^{15}+\xi^{20}=0$. Thus we have a sum of ten terms
$$1+\xi^5+\xi^{10}+\xi^{15}+\xi^{20}+\xi+\xi^6+\xi^{11}+\xi^{16}+\xi^{21}=0.$$ Here all the conditions 1-4 from my guessed list are met. And $10<\phi(25)=20$.

Comment: Are these two concepts related at all? I.e. the degree of the n-th cyclotomic polynomial and the number of terms in this type of sum. Perhaps there's some extra condition on the sum that I'm not seeing. Thanks for the counterexample by the way.

Comment: The minimal polynomial minimizes the degree of the polynomial, not the number of terms. A polynomial can have higher degree than it has terms, so they're not really related, no.

Comment: See [this post in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453698/15503) for more information (fixed the link). Particularly the comment by Gerry Myerson.